# How to make lowercase title in revealjs presentation in R?

Tags: html, css, r, reveal.js

I want to have a lowercase title in my revealjs presentation in R. Default title is uppercase and I can't find any built-in option to change it, so I created a piece of HTML code to do that.

My `a.html` file:

```
<style>
.title-custom {
text-align: right;
text-transform: lowercase;
}  
</style>   

<section>
    <h1 class="title-custom"><br> right lowercase title </h1>
</section>
```

My `index.Rmd` file:

````
---
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    theme: black
    highlight: pygments
    self_contained: false
    center: true
    reveal_options:
      slideNumber: true
      previewLinks: true
---
```{r, echo = FALSE}
shiny::includeHTML("a.html")
```
````

I get the output with one slide with right-aligned text (so the `index.Rmd` file 'sees' the `a.html` file) but still uppercase. What am I doing wrong and how to make the lowercase title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in `css` section I had to put `.reveal` right before my custom styling to override the default settings.

```
<style>
.reveal .title-custom {
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}  
</style>
```